# Xpath selenium WebDriver error in java program

Tags: selenium

I have a valid xpath but when i use the same Xpath in java to store the WebElements, it gives an error.
It is related to the syntax error.Below is the error 
syntax error on token ""]//div/div/button[@id="", 
     ( expected
    - Syntax error on token "header", delete this token
    - Syntax error on token ""]"", ) expected

```
below is the httml code


 <div id="header-wrap-container">
<div id="header-wrap" style="position: fixed;">
<div class="bredcrumDJV">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-5 col-lg-6">
<div class="col-md-7 col-lg-6 col-xs-12 applySec">
<div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
<button id="applybtn-2" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg dice-btn apply disableButton" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cover-resume-modal">Apply Now</button>
<div class="hidden-xs btn-group btn-group-lg">
<div class="visible-xs btn-group btn-group-lg btn-block">
<input id="partnerSurveyURL" value="https://partner.techpapers.com/interstitial/interstitial.aspx?promo=111186" type="hidden"/>
</div>
<div class="visible-xs">
<button id="applybtn-2" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg dice-btn apply disableButton" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cover-resume-modal">Apply Now</button>
<div class="hidden-xs btn-group btn-group-lg">
<div class="visible-xs btn-group btn-group-lg btn-block">
<input id="partnerSurveyURL" value="https://partner.techpapers.com/interstitial/interstitial.aspx?promo=111186" type="hidden"/>
</div>
<ul class="list-inline details pull-right djvReport hidden-xs" style="margin-top: 10px; clear: both;">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- START REPORT MODAL -->
```

xpath is  .//*[@id="header-wrap-container"]//div/div/button[@id="applybtn-2"]

inserted same xpath in java program.

```
public class FileUpload {
    @Test()
    public void checkAlertWindow() throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver webdriver = new FirefoxDriver();
    webdriver.get("https://www.dice.com/jobs/detail/Mobile-Test-Automation-Engineer-Etouch-Systems-Corp-Fremont-CA-94555/etouch/734212?icid=sr2-1p&q=NightWatch,Selenium&l=Fremont");
//By bye = By.xpath(".//*[@id="header-wrap-container"]");
    //  + "/button[@id="applybtn-2"]");
    //By b = By.xpath(".//*[@id="header-wrap-container"]");
//  webdriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id="header-wrap-container"]"));
    WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(webdriver, 10))
              .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("header-wrap-container")));
    System.out.println(myDynamicElement.getText());
    By byeid = By.id("header-wrap-container");
webdriver.findElement(By.xpath(" .//*[@id="header-wrap-container"]//div/div/button[@id="applybtn-2"]"));


}
}
```

why the program gives an error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either escape the " inside your statement or use '

Try this:

```
webdriver.findElement(By.xpath(" .//*[@id=\"header-wrap-container\"]//div/div/button[@id=\"applybtn-2\"]"));
```